# DHTMLX Scheduler with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have followed the DTHMLX Scheduler [tutorial](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/using-dhtmlxscheduler-with-node-js/), but I haven't been able to get the `db.event.insert()` to work, because the route for it is not firing off. However, I am able to display data from my MongoDB when I insert data through the shell.

Like the tutorial, I used MongoSkin as the MongoDB driver. Both MongoSkin and Express are the same version `"mongoskin": "~0.6.0"` & `"express": "~3.3.8"`as it is in the tutorial.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Basic initialization</title>
</head>
    <script src="codebase/dhtmlxscheduler.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codebase/dhtmlxscheduler.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

    
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }   
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function init() {
        scheduler.config.xml_date="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"; //changes date format   
        scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(),"month"); // when the calendar is initialized

        scheduler.templates.xml_date = function(value){ return new Date(value); };
        scheduler.load("/data", "json");    

        var dp = new dataProcessor("/data");
        dp.init(scheduler);
        dp.setTransactionMode("POST", true);
        console.log('init on index finished');
    }
</script>

<body onload="init();">
    <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
        <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
            <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_header">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_data">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The server file is pretty bare bones like the tutorial. The Server file is changed from app.js to server.js.

```
//server.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var db = require('mongoskin').db("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb", { w: 0});
    db.bind('event');


var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.bodyParser());


app.get('/init', function(req, res){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('before object');
    db.event.insert({ 
        text:"My test event A", 
        start_date: new Date(2017,5,1),
        end_date:   new Date(2017,5,5)
    }, console.log('first object run'));
    db.event.insert({ 
        text:"My test event B", 
        start_date: new Date(2017,5,19),
        end_date:   new Date(2017,5,24)
    });
    db.event.insert({ 
        text:"Morning event", 
        start_date: new Date(2017,5,4),
        end_date:   new Date(2017,5,4)
    });
    db.event.insert({ 
        text:"One more test event", 
        start_date: new Date(2017,5,3),
        end_date:   new Date(2017,5,8),
        color: "#DD8616"
    });
    res.send("Test events were added to the database");
    console.log('events inserted?')
});

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    db.event.find().toArray(function(err, data){
        //set id property for all records
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            // console.log('in for loop');
            data[i].id = data[i]._id;

        //output response
        res.send(data);
        console.log('data sent');
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on port 3000');
```

I am able to use the `app.get('/data'` route and callback function and get my collection printed onto the calendar, but only after inserting it in the MongoDB's shell command line.

The same can be said from inserting data, as `db.event.insert` method is missed because the `app.get('/init'` route never gets fired off. I found from testing, using console.logs.

I read through the DHTMLX Scheduler tutorial, the website's documentation, MongoDB documentation, and the MongoSkin docs. I could be completely missing an obvious solution, but I can't seem to find what I'm missing here so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> but I haven't been able to get the db.event.insert() to work, because the route for it is not firing off.

Seems like your code doesn't have a route for **POST /data** request, which is called when you insert/update/delete item on the client-side. Here is related code in the sample https://github.com/DHTMLX/node-scheduler-demo/blob/master/app.js#L52

Regarding **GET /init** route - it's only used to insert some test data into db,  and is called manually. You can remove it without any effect to the rest of the app

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.

I had that post data in previously but excluded for this question because I couldn't get the test data to work.

And putting the post back hasn't changed my results. I referred to their github repo. Still not sure what I did wrong.